# Is the nonlinear Schrödinger equation solved?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

Consider the following initial value problem:

$i\psi_t = -\psi_{xx} - 2|\psi|^2\psi$ with $x\in[0,2\pi)$ and $t\geq 0$, and $\psi(x,0) = \frac{3}{2}\left(1 - \frac{1}{10}\cos(x-\pi)\right)$.

The above in its more general form is called the Nonlinear Schrödinger's Equation. What I would like to know if the above can be solved analytically. I know that solutions to this problem exist, but it is not clear to me whether methods exist to produce solutions, given the boundary conditions.

Context of the question: I have to solve this thing numerically and I'd like to know more about the equation.

Comment: The non-linear Schrodinger equation has soliton solutions, so try making a travelling wave ansatz.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is a traveling wave ansatz?

Comment: $\psi=f(x-ct)$, where c is the speed of the wave to be determined by the equation

Comment: Just to be clear, must $\psi$ be of this form? Or are you suggesting to try it and hope for the best?